# C# LINQ Aggregate exist list

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a class like that:

```
     public class UserBadge {
         public int Id {get;set;}
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string Surname { get; set; }
         public string FiscalCode { get; set; }
         public int Hours { get; set; }
         public int Day { get; set; }
         public int Month { get; set; }
         public int Year { get; set; }
      }
```

And I fill with this data:

```
var listUserBadge = new List<UserBadge>;
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 1,
                                   Name = 'Mario',
                                   Surname = 'Rossi',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 8,
                                   Month = 1,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 4
                    });
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 1,
                                   Name = 'Mario',
                                   Surname = 'Rossi',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 4,
                                   Month = 2,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 4
                    });
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 1,
                                   Name = 'Mario',
                                   Surname = 'Rossi',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 8,
                                   Month = 1,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 10
                    });
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 2,
                                   Name = 'Pippo',
                                   Surname = 'Pluto',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 8,
                                   Month = 1,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 4
                    });
```

I want a linq command for aggregate for the same ID, month and year (don't care about day) summing hours, so something to make over existing data that equival to add data in this way:

```
var listUserBadge = new List<UserBadge>;
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 1,
                                   Name = 'Mario',
                                   Surname = 'Rossi',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 16,
                                   Month = 1,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 0
                    });
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 1,
                                   Name = 'Mario',
                                   Surname = 'Rossi',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 4,
                                   Month = 2,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 4
                    });
listUserBadge .Add(new UserBadge { Id = 2,
                                   Name = 'Pippo',
                                   Surname = 'Pluto',
                                   FiscalCode = 'XXXX',
                                   Hours = 8,
                                   Month = 1,
                                   Year = 2017,
                                   Day = 4
                    });
```

After that I will iterate for every data and extract a single .CSV, but this is another story. I don't figure out how to do that, can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try by yourself first: `.GroupBy(badge => new { badge.Id, badge.Year, badge.Month })...;` then tell us what specific problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `GroupBy`, you can supply this a key and sum the hours.

```
 var aggrData = listUserBadge
               .GroupBy(badge=>new { badge.Id,badge.Month, badge.Year})
               .Select(x=>new UserBadge {Id=x.Key.Id,
                                         Name = x.First().Name,
                                         Surname = x.First().Surname,
                                         Month = x.Key.Month,
                                         Year = x.Key.Year,
                                         Hours = x.Sum(y=>y.Hours)});
```